# How do I convince MFC's CScrollView to scroll by whole lines, not just by pixels?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, hex, scrollview

Exhausted! **How do I convince MFC's CScrollView to scroll by whole lines, not just by pixels?** I'm so desperate that I even took Jeff Procise's "Programming Windows with MFC" to copy & paste the trivial example found there. Without success...!

I'm extending a larger project with a rather simplified hexa editor and I've run into this nightmare. As it is usually the case, I'm missing something terribly small to make it work.

See the code below and the two versions of the `OnSize` handler which I susspect to be the source of problems. In each one of them, I'm: (a) determining the number of lines that represent a file (each line with 16 bytes, so for instance a 500 Bytes file is represented by 32 lines), and (b) setting parameters of the vertical scrollbar. If 32 lines are to be shown, I set the range to 0..32. Unfortunately, MFC takes this range as if it was in pixels instead of "lines", and I can't convince it to do otherwise in my `OnDraw` method.

Mentioning the `OnDraw` method, the problem visually seems like there was a clipping region that can't be removed by calling `myDC.SelectClipRgn(NULL);`. Aka, I can't draw in the area that Windows knew how to draw by itself by moving the original content. The problem, however, will quite certainly lay somewhere else...

```
// MFC message map set correctly

afx_msg int CHexaEditor::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs){
    // window created; instantiating the window manually
    if (CScrollView::OnCreate(lpcs)==-1) return -1;
    m_nMapMode=MM_TEXT;   // reason - see OnSize version 2
    m_lineDev=CSize(0,1); // reason - see OnSize version 2
}
void CHexaEditor::PostNcDestroy(){
    // window ready to be destroyed
    //nop (I'll do the job)
}

// OnSize handler version 1 (making use of MFC methods)
afx_msg void CHexaEditor::OnSize(UINT nType,int cx,int cy){
    // window size changed
    nLinesTotal=...;
    SetScrollSizes( MM_TEXT,
            CSize(0,nLinesTotal),
            ...page size...,
            CSize(0,1) // scroll up & down by one line
        );
    ShowScrollBar(SB_VERT,TRUE); // force visible
}

// OnSize handler version 2 (making use of API functions)
afx_msg void CHexaEditor::OnSize(UINT nType,int cx,int cy){
    // window size changed
    nLinesTotal=...;
    SCROLLINFO si={ sizeof(si), SIF_RANGE|SIF_PAGE, ... };
    SetScrollInfo( SB_VERT, &si, FALSE );
    ShowScrollBar(SB_VERT,TRUE); // force visible
}
```

Any help apreciated, thanks in advance!

Tomas

Answer (score 3):

In `CMyScrollView::OnCreate` add the following code

```
int res = CScrollView::OnCreate(lpcs);
SIZE  sizeTotal = { 0, line_height * line_total };
SIZE  sizeLine = { 0, line_height };
SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, sizeTotal, sizeTotal, sizeLine);
return res;
```

`line_height` is the height of each line in pixels. For example 20 pixels.

`line_total` is the total number of lines (not the total number of visible lines in each page, but the total number of lines from start to finish, including lines which are not visible)

See also: [CScrollView::SetScrollSizes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ew6s3ez.aspx)

Simply print the entire content. For example:

```
void CMyView::OnDraw(CDC* pdc)
{
    CMyDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    if (!pDoc) return;

    CString s;
    for (int i = 0; i < line_total; i++)
    {
        s.Format(L"line %d", i);
        pdc->TextOut(0, i * line_height, s);
    }
}
```

It's not necessary to change anything in `CMyScrollView::OnSize`, except for adjusting page size.

---

---

To make changes to `SCROLLINFO`, don't drive from `CScrollView`. Drive from `CView`instead. Add `ON_WM_VSCROLL` to message map to handle scroll messages.

```
void CMyView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    //you can also overload OnCreate to setup scroller
    CView::OnInitialUpdate();

    line_height = 18;
    line_total = 0xffff;

    SCROLLINFO info = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO) };
    info.nMin = 0;
    info.nMax = line_total;
    info.nPage = 1;
    info.fMask = SIF_ALL;
    SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &info, TRUE);
}

void CMyView::OnVScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    CView::OnVScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);

    SCROLLINFO info = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO) };
    GetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &info, SIF_ALL);
    
    int pos = info.nPos;
    switch (nSBCode)
    {
    case SB_LEFT: pos = info.nMin; break;
    case SB_RIGHT: pos = info.nMax; break;
    case SB_LINELEFT: pos--; break;
    case SB_LINERIGHT: pos++;  break;
    case SB_PAGELEFT: pos -= info.nPage; break;
    case SB_PAGERIGHT: pos += info.nPage; break;
    case SB_THUMBPOSITION: pos = info.nTrackPos; break;
    case SB_THUMBTRACK: pos = info.nTrackPos; break;
    }

    //make sure the new position is within range
    if (pos < info.nMin) pos = info.nMin;
    int max = info.nMax - info.nPage + 1;
    if (pos > max) pos = max;

    info.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    info.nPos = pos;
    SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &info, FALSE);

    Invalidate(FALSE);
}

void CMyView::OnDraw(CDC* pdc)
{
    CMyDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    CRect rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);

    SCROLLINFO info = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO) };
    info.fMask = SIF_ALL;
    GetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &info, SIF_POS);

    //find the start and end posion, print the visible portion
    int start = info.nPos;
    int end = start + rc.Height() / line_height;
    if (end > line_total) end = line_total;
    for (int i = start, y = 0; i < end; i++, y += line_height)
    {
        CString s;
        s.Format(_T("line %i"), i);
        pdc->TextOut(0, y, s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your `sizeLine` parameter is the number of pixels to scroll if the arrow buttons are pressed, not the size of the line. So it has no effect on the slider. Besides, there's still the problem with me being unable to paint into the region that Windows has moved (in my favour) from one place to another in response to scrolling.

Comment: The line size is n-pixels, it will scroll by that amount. You can also drive from `CView` and setup the scroller. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the nice suggestions, they have broaden my view :-)

Anyway, answering now my own question as I've decided to reject the way via `CScrollView` and do things using `CEdit`. I'd go the way of even more general `CWnd` (or `CView` as suggested above) but for some strange reason, these don't accept input focus if parented by `CSplitterWnd`. So after quite rigorously exploring the behaviour of `CScrollView` in different scrolling situations, I no longer thing that this would be an easy (or even feasible!) way. The main reason is `CScrollView` itself - it calls `ScrollWindow` that sets the clipping area (client area minus "area that Windows knew how to draw") which I didn't manage to influence. Like I said, a much better way is either to derrive the thing from `CEdit` (or `CEditView`), or to create the thing using pure WinAPI - in either case, I can count right in lines and don't need to undertake round-trips to and from pixel counts. I've chosen MFC's `CEdit` as I don't want to bother myself with COM when it comes to copying, pasting, etc. If anyone is interested, [here](http://nestorovic.hyperlink.cz/__comms__/mfcHexaSrc.zip)'s what I've got so far (wastly uninteractive viewer at the moment).

Yet two spots on what was wrong in the `CScrollView` way: (1) the main problem wasn't in the `OnSize` handler - it was in the drawing routine where I was combining essentially three different ideas (scrolling by lines, scrolling by pixels, and Jeff Procise's scrolling by pixels), which let to incoherenes in drawing code that followed once `CDC::GetClipBox` was called - that's why I wasn't able to paint everywhere in the visible "canvas"; and (2) missing `return` statement in the `OnCreate` handler - returning a random result (non-zero, indicating a failure), I had to manually show the scrollbar.

Hope this helps someone who also wants to scroll things by whole lines in MFC.